# Unable to process server request using PHP

Tags: php

Previous question was asked but with no answers, I am encountering this error and I would like some assistance please. I am trying to connect to 2 different servers and retrieve data from both, and display it under 1 search button using the price.

The index.php is a simple button on a page, that's all.

The function search_by_price.php is the SQL query running to obtain information from the 2 defines servers it is connecting to.

The error I am receiving is: **error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document**

Thanks.

SQL statement referenced:

```
 public XmlDocument SearchAccommodationByPrice(string Price)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string query = "select " + allFields + " from Accommodations a, Users u, AccommodationImages i where"
                        + " a.AccommodationPrice=@Price and u.userID = a.UserID and a.imgID = i.imgID";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlCommand.Connection = connection;
        sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Accommodations");
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Accommodations_List");

        XmlDocument xmlDom = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDom.LoadXml(dataSet.GetXml());

        return xmlDom;

       }
}
```

Here is my index.php code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <title>Property Search</title> 
        <meta name="ds364" content="ds364@greenwich.ac.uk" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/lumen/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Search Property Information</h1>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Property By Price</h2>
                <form method="GET" action="search_by_price.php">
                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="price">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

Here is my php:

```
    '<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled",0); 


if(isset($_REQUEST['price']))
{
  $price = $_REQUEST['pprice'];
}

// This is to access .NET service
$args = array('price'=>$price); 
$client = new SoapClient('http://stuiis.cms.gre.ac.uk/ds364/ServiceOrientedWeb/AccommodationSearch.asmx?WSDL'); 
$xmls = $client->SearchAccommodationByPrice($price)->SearchAccommodationByPriceResult->any; 
$xmlDom1 = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDom1->loadXML($xmls); 

//print_r($xmlDom1);

// This is to access Level 3 service (PHP Webservice)
$url = 'http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ds364/lvl3/search_by_price.php'.$price; 
$xmlDom2 = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDom2->load($url); 


//print_r($xmlDom2);
// This is to combine the services of PHP Webservice and .NET webservice
$xmlRoot1 = $xmlDom1->documentElement; 
foreach ( $xmlDom2->documentElement->childNodes as $node2 ) { 
    $node1 = $xmlDom1->importNode($node2,true); 
   $xmlRoot1->appendChild($node1); 
}

echo $xmlDom1->saveXML();

?>'
```

Here is my error:

```
     <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@Price nvarchar(4000))select a.AccommodationID,a.AccommodationN' expects the parameter '@Price', which was not supplied.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClien in <b>/home/ds364/public_nginx/search_by_price.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
```

Comment: You must define the problem in more detail. Nobody wants to read all the code and search a possible problem.

Comment: Edited. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is a typo:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['price']))
{
  $price = $_REQUEST['pprice'];
}
```

You wrote `pprice`, double p.

Comment: this is probably more a comment rather than an answer

Comment: The is the variable naming on one of the servers I am attempting to connect to, so I think this is correct as it needs to match on the receiving server.

Comment: @user1967788 the issue being pointed out here is not the actual name, just the mismatch in the if block - you check for the existence of one key `price` but then use another, that probably doesnt exist `pprice`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a multitude of issues going on here:

**1)**
*PHP needs to be declared before any output is sent to the browser. This includes whitespace.*

```
    '<?php 
^^^^ This whitespace is being sent to the browser, 
// then you're sending header data, this is bad syntax
// and will throw errors.

header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

**2)**
One of your errors (*Fatal Error*, line 1) references an SQL statement but you have not shown us in the question what your SQL statement is. Please update your question.

**3)**
The error clearly states you should be looking at:

```
/home/ds364/public_nginx/search_by_price.php on line **14**
```

This is note code you've shown us, as yet.

> **What does the above file/line state?**

**4)**
As referenced by [Shutterfly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42754160/3536236) you have a fundamental inconsistency here:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['price']))
{
  $price = $_REQUEST['pprice'];
}
```

Why are you asking if one value `price` is set, before the setting using another value `pprice`. One of these is almost certainly a typo. Let me make it a bit clearer:

- *Why would you* or *are you **sure** you* intend to do this:

  ```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['value1']))
      {
        $price = $_REQUEST['value_2'];
      }
  ```

***I THINK THIS IS YOUR ISSUE***

> expects the parameter '@Price', which was not supplied.

```
$xmls = $client->SearchAccommodationByPrice($price)->SearchAccommodationByPriceResult->any;
```

The value of `$price` is undefined (`null`) due to the issue **4**, above.

Comment: Your issue 3 is the same as what you've identified as the issue, I have added the SQL query within the question and made the other changes you've suggested, however no luck.

Comment: @user1967788 is `Here is my php: ` referencing to the `search_by_price.php` file?